# good jquery slider for 960px site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, image

I'd like to know what is a good pre-coded jquery slider, but specifically for a 960px site. Also its purpose would be just to auto slide, not worried about buttons so much

I plan to use it with the 960 grid system and have it span across 12 columns
Cheers ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ as a good slider. It can accomodate images of any size, so it will work regardless of being a 960px site.

Comment: lol was looking at that, u read my mind :P. can u disable the transparent borders around it if need be?

Comment: Everything is customizable via CSS :-)

Comment: ok last question, regarding arrows and bullets provided, where are the links as i plan on using an img folder, not calling it images.

Comment: also confused about the fact that it only references jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js and doesnt reference the other jquery.nivo.slider.js on the site guide.

Comment: the pack.js version is simply a minified version of the same file (it doesn't include comments, whitespace, etc to make the file size smaller).

Comment: ah k. i think i basically got it running smooth as now. the url is at http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/2. as u can see i got the arrows in, but one of ems rotated the wrong way, shall be fixed with css though